# Bootstrap way of handling light text on light background?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

What's the appropriate way to handle light text on (possibly) light backgrounds (e.g. over images, where the contents of the image are generally unknown, but could easily be white or very light)?

[Here](https://nomadlist.com/) is an example of some effects:

[image]

Note, importantly, that even on a pure white background, the words would still be (juust) possible to read.

I tried to emulate this with bootstrap 4, with this:

```html
<span class="text-light shadow-lg">
My text
<span>
```

But this did not seem to work - I could not get the effect to appear.

Since it's a common problem, I hope bootstrap has a native way for handling for this sensibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap is not providing a text-shadow styling.
You could use `text-light` and customize your shadow.

```css
/* just for demo */
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
 text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="text-light">text</span>
```

Comment: Brilliant. For any dummies like me, the critical bit is `text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 5px;`